# Need to add a Zoo Visitor to mailchimp on registration - options?

Tags: zoo-visitor, mailchimp

I'm using Zoo Visitor to handle membership on an EE2.6.1 site and my client would like members to have the option to add themselves to their mailchimp account when filling out the member registration form.
I'm seeing a number of mailchimp add-ons on Devot-ee but none that mention zoo visitor.
What are my options? Any one been succesful in doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Does this help from the Zoo Visitor docs? 
http://ee-zoo.com/docs/visitor/tutorial/mailchimp-integration.html

Comment: D'oh - totally missed that one - let's hope @monooso's extension still works. Thanks Jim!

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to use that, but the extension is not really maintained, see http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/zoo-visitor/viewthread/8499. Would love to know if it works now, but I have my doubts.

If that still fails, you could insert a script directly in ext.zoo_visitor.php on line 337 with the api file next to it:http://www.joshuawinn.com/subscribe-to-mailchimp-newsletter-option-on-contact-form/ But then maintenance might be an issue.

I ended up with a two step process: during subscription, if someone activates the tick box for mailing, after submit they will be directed to a page with hidden fields and the subscription button that leads directly to mailchimp. So that's one click extra.

Didn't see it was you Erwin, you can check it in Dutch here: http://divmo.nl/klanten/login (aanmelden)

Comment: Can attest that @monooso 's extension does indeed still work on EE2.6.1 and with Mailchimp's current api.

Comment: Ah thanks, might give it a re-try then. It just wouldn't work half a year ago.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the SL MailChimp Subscribe add-on to work in 2.7.2. I was able to do the following, though:

Setup a checkbox field, called `optincheckbox`, with a value of "y". Install [MailChimp EE](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mailchimp-ee), and add something like this to your template in an area where your members will be logged in:

```
 {exp:zoo_visitor:details}
    {if visitor:member_optincheckbox == "y"}
        {exp:mailchimp_ee:subscribe 
            api_key="KEY HERE"
            list_id="KEY HERE"
            email_address="{visitor:email}" 
            interest_groups='GROUP HERE'
            merge_fname='{visitor:member_firstname}'
            merge_lname='{visitor:member_lastname}'
            double_optin='no'
        }
    {if:else}
        {exp:mailchimp_ee:unsubscribe
            api_key="KEY HERE"
            list_id="KEY HERE"
            email_address="{visitor:email}"
        }
    {/if}
{/exp:zoo_visitor:details}
```